# WebScraping Aliexpress - Lazyloading

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape Aliexpress using Selenium and Python. I'm doing it by following a youtube tutorial, I have followed every steps but I just can't seem to get it to work.

I tried to use requests, BeautifulSoup as well. But it seems like Aliexpress uses lazy loaders on their product listings. I tried using the window scroll script but that didn't work. It seems like the content would not load until I personally scroll on it.

This is the url for the page I would like to web scrape
https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?trafficChannel=main&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=dog+supplies&ltype=wholesale&SortType=default&g=n

This is the code I have currently. It doesn't return anything in the output. I think that's because it's trying to go through all the product listings but it couldn't find any because it's not loaded...

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated, sorry for the bad formatting and the bad code in advance.

Thank you!

```
"""
To do
HOT PRODUCT FINDER Enter: Keyword, to generate a url

Product Name
Product Image
Product Link
Sales Number
Price
Create an excel file that contains these data
Sort the list by top selling orders
Develop an algorithm for the velocity of the product (total sales increased / time?)
Scrape site every day """

import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import requests
import lxml

#Starting Up the web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# grab Keywords
search_term = input('Keywords: ')

# url generator

def get_url(search_term):
    """Generate a url link using search term provided"""
    url_template = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?trafficChannel=main&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText={}&ltype=wholesale&SortType=default&g=n'
    search_term = search_term.replace(" ", "+")
    return url_template.format(search_term)

url = get_url('search_term')
driver.get(url)

#scrolling down to the end of the page
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')

#Extracting the Collection
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='list product-card')
print(productlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import requests
import lxml
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver.exe',options = chrome_options)
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# grab Keywords
search_term = input('Keywords: ')

# url generator
driver.get('https://www.aliexpress.com')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)


p = driver.find_element_by_name('SearchText')
p.send_keys(search_term)
p.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

productlist = []
product = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul')

height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
for scrol in range(100,height-1800,100):
    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0,{scrol})")
    time.sleep(0.5)
# driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
div = []
list_i = []
item_title = []
a = []
for z in range(1,16):                     
    div.append(product.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/div'+str([z])))
for pr in div:
    list_i.append(pr.find_elements_by_class_name('list-item'))
for pc in list_i:
    for p in pc:
        item_title.append(p.find_element_by_class_name('item-title-wrap'))
for pt in item_title:
    a.append(pt.find_element_by_tag_name('a'))
for prt in a:
    productlist.append(prt.text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried out the code. It didn't seem to work. I think I just picked a very hard website to web scrape for my first project. The website has lazy loaders I'm not sure how to bypass that.

Comment: i updated my code again take a look its return all element names in the item list

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying once again. I tried out the code, it's giving me this error.  selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)

Answer (score 0):

Aliexpress uses lazy load to load a list of products. But you can send POST requests to the https://www.aliexpress.com/fn/search-pc/index
It output a complete list of products in json format with price, link to images, etc. I scraped most of the catalogs from aliexpress this way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).